# In AngularJS can I stop browser rendering until digest is complete?

Tags: angularjs

I have a Bootstrap input group that displays differently depending on its state.  Checking the box cause the textbox to display and unchecking it hide the textbox.
I have to adjust the width of the label to have it line up correctly with and without the textbox

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="bcc.switchState(item)">
        <button class="btn btn-default chkitem-btn"
            aa-box-click="item.isNotOK">
        </button>
    </div>
    <label class="input-group-addon checkbox-label"
            ng-click="bcc.switchState(item)"
            ng-class="{
                default: !item.isNotOK,
                checked: item.isNotOK,
                'checkbox-label-textbox': item.hasTextbox && item.isNotOK
                }">
            {{item.caption}}
    </label>
    <input id="txt{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control text"
            ng-model="item.text" ng-show="item.hasTextbox && item.isNotOK">
</div>
```

My problem is that Angular adjusts the width of the label before it hides the textbox, which is distracting to the user.   Is there any way I can prevent any changes from rendering until the digest loop is complete?

Comment: can you post the code where you change the size?

Comment: Did you try with [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)?

Comment: I think css property 'transition' can be checked in this case. Try using it.

Comment: @sebenalern No code the checkbox-label-textbox class changes the label width from 1% to 100%

Comment: @pasine  ng-clock works on a page loading from the server.  The behavior I  am trying to affect is all on the client

Comment: Is it possible you could make a plunker so I can look at it. I have an idea but I want to test it first